# Does windows CE 7.0 has same API and functionality with normal windows system programming?

Tags: windows, serial-port, windows-ce, tcp

I Want to know if `Windows CE 7.0` has same API and functionality with normal `Windows` system programming.

For example, i have to deal with `serial(RS-232)`, `TCP/IP`, `select()` and so on  in `Windows CE 7.0`.

Can i use all of API same as normal `Windows`?

Or there are some Difference between them ?

Comment: The API is documented separately, so presumably there are some differences.  I believe they are fairly similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API are similar, but you should expect some differences.
For example serial port drivers may not support asynchronous read/writes. This is supported in the OS (since ver 7.0), but I have seen no drivers actually using it.
Also socket API is similar but, as you know, evil hides in details.
As a general rule you can't take for granted that software running on Windows desktop (or "normal" if you prefer :)) will just need a rebuild to run on CE.
It will need *at least* a rebuild (and sometimes this may be clumsy if you are using different releases of Visual Studio).